# COUNTIF COLUMN A is GREATER THAN COLUMN B

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
     A.         B. 
1. $0.00......$129.57
2. $139.14...$129.57
3. $539.00...$136.50
```

Basically, I am trying to ONLY Count the Number of cells in Column A if they are greater than those in column B. So for the above spreadsheet I would want the result to be 2.

I know it's got to be simple but the variations I'm trying aren't working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is via this array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNT(if(A1:A3>B1:B3,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! Much appreciated